# How to loop in dictionary with list of dictionaries in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have the following structure

```
volumeGroupName:
  - name: datavg1
    log_lv:
      name: logs_lv
      size: "1G"
    app_lv:
      name: apps_lv
      size: 2G
    project_lv:
      name: projects_lv
      size: 3G
  - name: datavg2
    log_lv:
      name: logs_lv
      size: "4G"
```

And I want to iterate through all the items. What I tried was using **with_subelements**, but I can get only one category like **apps_lvm** and I tried also **wih_dict** property but I couldn't obtain what I wanted.

Maybe the structure I'm using for variables is not the correct one??

Comment: Could you explain your playbook?

Comment: I was able to obtain what I wanted by changing the structure of variables.

Comment: - hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    volumeGroupName:
    - vg_name: datavg1
      lvms:
        - name: logs_lv
          size: "1G"
        - name: apps_lv
          size: 2G
        - name: projects_lv
          size: 3G
    - vg_name: datavg2
      lvms:
        - name: logs_lv
          size: "4G"
  tasks:
    - name: "Debug variables"
      debug:
        msg: "vg_name = {{ item.0.vg_name }} lvms_names={{ item.1.name }} size= {{ item.1.size}}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ volumeGroupName }}"
        - lvms

          size: "4G"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary of lists from the list of dictionaries. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        GroupVolumeList: "{{ dict(my_groups|zip(my_volumes)) }}"
      vars:
        my_groups: "{{ volumeGroupName|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
        my_volumes: "{{ volumeGroupName|map('dict2items')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: GroupVolumeList
```

gives

```yaml
  GroupVolumeList:
    datavg1:
    - key: name
      value: datavg1
    - key: log_lv
      value:
        name: logs_lv
        size: 1G
    - key: app_lv
      value:
        name: apps_lv
        size: 2G
    - key: project_lv
      value:
        name: projects_lv
        size: 3G
    datavg2:
    - key: name
      value: datavg2
    - key: log_lv
      value:
        name: logs_lv
        size: 4G
```

Then use *with_subelements*. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }}
              {{ item.1.key }}
              {{ item.1.value.name }}
              {{ item.1.value.size }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ GroupVolumeList|dict2items }}"
        - value
      when: item.1.key != 'name'
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: datavg1 log_lv logs_lv 1G
  msg: datavg1 app_lv apps_lv 2G
  msg: datavg1 project_lv projects_lv 3G
  msg: datavg2 log_lv logs_lv 4G
```